# Adding azure devops work item to a specific sprint

Tags: azure-devops

Ok so i have a work item in azure devops. This work item is currently not associated with any sprint.

Now i need to associate this work item with a sprint. But i cant find any information on how in the world to do this. When i have the sprint open, I can see this bit of text

[image]

But, I dont know what in the world i am supposed to be dragging, my full list of work item are not available like that, and also it is not clear where i need to drag them to

Thank you

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: did you read my question?

Comment: Yes. You said "I can't find any information". Where did you look? What did you try? What didn't work with what you tried? There's extensive documentation on how to use the work management tools.

Comment: sry, i looked in the docs, there i could only find info on how to add new work items, not existing ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Adding azure devops work item to a specific sprint

You could open that work item and change the Iteration field to the specify sprint.

As test, I have create a specify sprint `TestSprint` and a work item `TestWorkItem`, and the work item not associated with any sprint:

[image]

Then, we just need to change the Iteration field to the specify sprint `MyTestProject\TestSprint`:

[image]

Now, that work item associated with specify sprint:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to do add existing items from the sprint view? Its kind of hassle to have to go through all work items individually.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have Sprints defined in your system.
Second, to allocate work items into sprints you need to change the iteration field in the work item to the sprint.

[Work item sprint allocation by changing the iteration path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdQSF.png)